# How to compare ZonedDateTime (Spring Boot) with Date (TypeScript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, date, zoneddatetime

My Spring Data REST returns a ZonedDateTime date format like `2022-04-29T00:00:00+02:00` and in TypeScript (Angular) I have dates as `Sat Apr 23 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200`.

My goal is to compare two date converting the ZonedDateTime to the required format in Angular. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both `Strings` as you already have them to create the Date object, using the constructor. The constructor understands both forms.

```
let val1 : Date = new Date('2022-04-29T00:00:00+02:00');
let val2 : Date = new Date('Fri Apr 29 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200');
```

Then you can compare both objects using the `getTime()` method which returns an absolute representation in miliseconds

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since the
> ECMAScript epoch.

```
if (val1.getTime() === val2.getTime()){
  console.log('true');
}
```